# Waitbar results in many figures open - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

So, I have create a MATLAB script which takes a couple of minutes to execute. I decided to add a waitbar in correspondance with the documentation here: http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html

I have defined it as follows:

```
function crazyfunction4you();

h = waitbar(0,'Setting up...')

for i =1:N
    waitbar(i/N,'Loading...')
 %Some calculations is going on here

end

close(h);

end
```

Somehow, this is opening an insance amount of figures ultimately crashing my machine. I find this kind of weird since I would expect only one figure to appear:

[image]

I am interested in hearing weather you guys have similar experiences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include the handle to the waitbar, otherwise Matlab interprets you want to create another one:

```
h = waitbar(0,'Setting up...')
for i =1:N
    waitbar(i/N,h,'Loading...') %// Only this line changed. Added a handle
                                %// to refer to previously created waitbar
    %Some calculations is going on here
end
close(h);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Luis Mendo's answer, you might want to consider how often that waitbar is going to be updated, because if `N` is very big, updating the waitbar in every loop iteration can add a ridiculous amount of overhead.

To remedy that, do something like

```
k = 0.1; % // determines how often bar is updated, 0.1 means every 10%, 0.05 means
         % // every 5% etc.

h = waitbar(0,'Setting up...')
for i =1:N
    if mod(i/N,k)==0                % // added to supress unnecessary waitbar updates
        waitbar(i/N,h,'Loading...')
    end                        
    %Some calculations is going on here
end
close(h);
```